# Posting an image to a reply using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post an image from a URL to reply to a certain comment on Facebook. The Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/ mentions that you can publish an image from a URL using the 'attachment_url' field.

When I try that in Graph API explorer by posting `attachment_url` to `{comment_id}/comments`, I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 2
  }
}
```

If I try to post a `message`, it works perfectly, but `attachment_url` doesn't work, even though the documentation mentions it. Anybody has any idea what's going on here?

NOTE: I wanna first try to knock it off using the Graph API Explorer, then I would move to my desired language. As such, I don't have any code to paste here. Thanks

Comment: so it turns out, it was a bug in the API: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1487638524783972

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in the API and about 2 weeks after my report, Facebook has finally resolved this. Here is the bug report:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1487638524783972